# How can I automate testing a Template Haskell function?

Tags: haskell, automated-tests, template-haskell

I [defined a function](https://github.com/frerich/catamorphism/blob/master/src/Data/Morphism/Cata.hs#L138) using Template Haskell which generates a function definition given some type. The type is basically

```
makeFunc :: Name -> Q [Dec]
```

Right now, I use the `-ddump-splices` switch with GHC to see the generated splices. How can I automate this to verify that different types yield the expected splices?

A basic approach might be to just redirect the generated splice to a file and then compare that, but the generated code may well be different since it involves various identifiers constructed via [`newName`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.10.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v:newName).

Comment: Is it enough to just use `runQ :: Q a -> IO a`? Then you can write any (decidable) predicate on `a` that you like, including alpha-equivalence to a known-good result from a previous run.

Comment: Maybe you could write a really obnoxious `equalModuloNames :: Dec -> Dec -> Bool` function that ignores names, and then do some unit tests with your generated code. Together that seems like it would provide decent coverage.